# Delphi Android JMediaScannerConnection

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface

My app writes files into a folder on the internal (or external) SD card but those files are not seen via **MTP**.

I found a solution in Java to utilize `MediaScannerConnection.scanfile().Androidapi.JNI.Media` which contains `TJMediaScannerConnection` but I did not find any help on how to use it.

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
use  Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.Jni.Media;
```

...

```
  procedure TForm1.UpdateMTP;
  var
    c: Integer;
    JMediaScannerCon: Androidapi.Jni.Media.JMediaScannerConnection;
    JMediaScannerCon_Client: Androidapi.Jni.Media.JMediaScannerConnection_MediaScannerConnectionClient;
  begin
    JMediaScannerCon:=TJMediaScannerConnection.JavaClass.init(SharedActivityContext, JMediaScannerCon_Client);
    JMediaScannerCon.connect;
    c:=0;
    while not JMediaScannerCon.isConnected do begin
      Sleep(100);
      inc(c);
      if (c>20) then break;
    end;
    if (JMediaScannerCon.isConnected) then begin
      JMediaScannerCon.scanFile(StringToJString(sYourPath), nil);
      JMediaScannerCon.disconnect;
    end;
  end);
```

I use a polling to check if connected, a better way is to use the events of JMediaScannerCon, but I did not try it.

Comment: This works perfectly, only windows seems to cache the content. If I disconnect and reconnect the device the fresh content is immediately visible. Deleted the comment about this problem. Enny - Thanks a lot, this saved my day.

Comment: I am very happy that it worked for you. So you can mark my answer as solution.